# How can I use python3 for profantiy editor mini project?

Tags: python, http, http-status-code-404

```
[This is the error output.][1]I've tried using urllib.parse also to parse the value but nothing helps.Please help me out. I'm a beginner in Python.

    import urllib.request

    def text_finder():
        songs=open("C:\song.txt")
        contents=songs.read()
        songs.close()
        profanity(contents)

    def profanity(text_to_check):    
        connection=urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+text_to_check)
        output=connection.read()
        connection.close()
        if "true" in output:
            print("No curse word in text.")
        elif "false" in output:
            print("There is curse word in your text!")
        else:
            print("Something went wrong!")

    text_finder()
```

This is the error message output.
Please help me out. 
     RESTART: C:\Users\simra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\profanityeditor.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\simra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\profanityeditor.py", line 18, in 
        text_finder()
      File "C:\Users\simra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\profanityeditor.py", line 6, in text_finder
        profanity(contents)
      File "C:\Users\simra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\profanityeditor.py", line 9, in profanity
        connection=urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+text_to_check)
      File "C:\Users\simra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "C:\Users\simra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "C:\Users\simra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "C:\Users\simra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "C:\Users\simra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Users\simra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not images. This particular error message is a HTTP error code telling you that the URL you request does not exist.

Comment: @eukaryota but the url exists.

Comment: can you in some way show us/ verify that text_to_check isn't empty